# How to add text in the background image in Bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, background-image

I am designing the Bootstrap form. I wanted to add text in the background image just like this: http://dubaiexporters.com/member_benefits.aspx. I tried the below code but the text is not fitting well inside the background image.

[image]

I am new to Bootstrap.

Code:

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="silverAds">
                        <div class="adContent">
                            <ul><li><a href="pdf/Dubai_Exporters_Member_Certficate.pdf" target="_blank">DubaiExporters Membership Certificate </a></li> 
                                <li>Log in to access and edit the Company profile. </li>
                                <li>Access to the latest inquiries received from agents, importers, distributors all
                                    over the world.</li>
                                <li>Company’s Logo , profile & the website link in the Supplier’s section.</li>
                                <li>Advertisement of the Company shall be included in the Listing.</li>
                                <li>Weekly Newsletter updates from Dubai Exporters containing latest news about the
                                    world economy, export scenarios, upcoming projects, trade events, market reviews
                                    and the link to the Member’s Profile on Dubai Exporters, shall be mailed to our
                                    entire database of over 150000 Importers from Africa, CIS,Eastern Europe, latin
                                    America, Asia.&nbsp;<a class="lightbox" href="images/newslettertemplate.jpg">View sample</a></li>
                                <li>A CD of Dubai Exporters shall be distributed to all the trade visitors and importers
                                    visiting Int’l trade exhibitions where Dubai Exporters participates, thereby making
                                    your company’s information reach the right target audience. </li>
                            </ul>
                            <div style="float: right; padding:15px 60px 0px 0px;">
                                <asp:ImageButton ID="btSilver" runat="server" ImageUrl="images/mem_btn.png"
                                     /></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
 .silverAds
{


    background: url(  'images/SILVER-member.jpg' ) no-repeat center 0;
    height: 372px;
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0px 0px 20px 0px;
    width:100%;
}

 .adContent
{
    padding:80px 80px 0px 65px;
    width:87%;
}

div.adContent li
{

    font-family :Arial;
    font-size: 12px;
    list-style-image: none;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    line-height:16px;

}
div.adContent li a{color:#FFFFFF; text-decoration:underline;}
```

Comment: which section in the given URL are you referring to?

Comment: @RupeshJain.. http://dubaiexporters.com/member_benefits.aspx Silver Member

Answer (score 0):

**Use `background-size: 100% 100%;` and `height: 100%;`**

See fiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/5shda4pc/2/

```css
 .silverAds
{
    background-image: url('https://material.angular.io/assets/img/examples/shiba1.jpg');
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px 0px 20px 0px;
    width:100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}

 .adContent
{
    padding:80px 80px 0px 65px;
    width:87%;
}

div.adContent li
{

    font-family :Arial;
    font-size: 12px;
    list-style-image: none;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    line-height:16px;

}
div.adContent li a{color:#FFFFFF; text-decoration:underline;}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="silverAds">
    <div class="adContent">
      <ul><li><a href="pdf/Dubai_Exporters_Member_Certficate.pdf" target="_blank">DubaiExporters Membership Certificate </a></li> 
        <li>Log in to access and edit the Company profile. </li>
        <li>Access to the latest inquiries received from agents, importers, distributors all
                                    over the world.</li>
        <li>Company’s Logo , profile & the website link in the Supplier’s section.</li>
        <li>Advertisement of the Company shall be included in the Listing.</li>
        <li>Weekly Newsletter updates from Dubai Exporters containing latest news about the
                                    world economy, export scenarios, upcoming projects, trade events, market reviews
                                    and the link to the Member’s Profile on Dubai Exporters, shall be mailed to our
                                    entire database of over 150000 Importers from Africa, CIS,Eastern Europe, latin
                                    America, Asia.&nbsp;<a class="lightbox" href="images/newslettertemplate.jpg">View sample</a></li>
         <li>A CD of Dubai Exporters shall be distributed to all the trade visitors and importers
                                    visiting Int’l trade exhibitions where Dubai Exporters participates, thereby making
                                    your company’s information reach the right target audience. </li>
                            </ul>
                            <div style="float: right; padding:15px 60px 0px 0px;">
                                <asp:ImageButton ID="btSilver" runat="server" ImageUrl="images/mem_btn.png"
                                     /></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i have used it but when i resize it,the text inside the background image goes out from down..

Comment: resize the page or use other `width` to `silverAds`??

Comment: see...i put the image above

Comment: use this image and see...text goes out... http://dubaiexporters.com/images/SILVER-member.jpg

Comment: text is going down

Comment: do you want on resize scroll will show and the image stay big??

Comment: According to screen size,the text in the background image should adjust or fit.So when i minimise the browser window,the text in the background image should adjust.

Comment: see in fiddle it exactly what happened:https://jsfiddle.net/5shda4pc/5/

Comment: use exactlly my code (remove `height:` from `adContent`)

Comment: text still goes down when resize

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174320/discussion-between---and-chetan-kambli).